# Making an asynchronous call to load a js file not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a div which has the following contents

```
<div id="xyz">
 <script src="https://seal.verisign.com/getseal?host_name=esewa.com.np&amp;size=S&amp;use_flash=YES&amp;use_transparent=YES&amp;lang=en"></script>.
</div>
```

After loading the script, a flash file gets returned and gets displayed in the div

Now I tried loading the same script in the follow manner

```
<div id="xyz">

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
                 getVerisignCertificate();
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

And the function body is

```
function getVerisignCertificate(){
    scriptObject = document.createElement('script');
    scriptObject.type = 'text/javascript';
    scriptObject.async = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:"https://seal.verisign.com/getseal?host_name=esewa.com.np&amp;size=S&amp;use_flash=YES&amp;use_transparent=YES&amp;lang=en",
        dataType: "script",
        success: function(data) {
            scriptObject.src= data ;
            $(window).load(function(){
                $("head").append(scriptObject);      
            });
        }
    }); 
}
```

the connnection to the remote server gets established however the flash file is not displayed .What exactly am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried entering some debugger point so that you may be able to see what happens when the code enters  getVerisignCertificate() method

Comment: Why do you want to do that via AJAX if the first option works? You could use `$.getScript()`;

Comment: @putvande I did that too and I get the same issue.Thanks for teh suggestion though

Comment: $.getScript is the best option to load javascript in run time

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com Well I agree the same issue persists that way too.

Comment: window onload event is no more fired once already fired

Comment: Getting the script with ajax and setting the returned data as the source of a script tag makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 2):

The most effective, fastest and best way is to use Google's Analytics Async method.

Copy paste this:

```
(function() {
  var as = document.createElement('script'); as.type = 'text/javascript'; as.async = true;
  as.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'https://') + 'seal.verisign.com/getseal?host_name=esewa.com.np&amp;size=S&amp;use_flash=YES&amp;use_transparent=YES&amp;lang=en';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(as, s);
})();
```

More on this method can be found at [Google's Analytics Development Overview](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking to use `scriptObject.text=data;` rather than `scriptObject.src=data;`
Also, you're probably wanting to append it id xyz `$('#xyz').append(scriptObject);` instead of head.

Answer (score -1):

You can load the script this way:

```
$("head").append("<script src='https://seal.verisign.com/getseal?host_name=esewa.com.np&amp;size=S&amp;use_flash=YES&amp;use_transparent=YES&amp;lang=en'>");
```